# Set a pugixml node to null?

Tags: c++, reference, xml-parsing, pugixml

In [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/documentation/) the type `pugi::xmlnode` is an object for referencing parts of an XML tree.  Being vaguely pointer-like, these objects can be *null*.  The pugi library often returns null nodes, but how can I create one myself?

*[update]* Perhaps "creating" a null node is not what I want.  I actually want to take an existing node object and make it nul.

Comment: "*Perhaps "creating" a null node is not what I want. I actually want to take an existing node object and make it nul.*" How exactly do you intend to do that? Do you mean to *remove* the node from the document? Remember: an `xml_node` is a *reference* to a node, not the node itself. So making the reference null will do nothing to the node.

Comment: Hmm, I used too many words, by "node object" I meant a C++ object, not an XML node.  So yes, existing ones can indeed be made null.  This does not have to mean the removing the node from the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
pugi:xml_node node(NULL);
```

Comment: Turns out that `xml = pugi::xml_node();` solves my problem.  I can also give NULL as an argument and it doesn't complain - although this usage doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: pugi::xml_node() is the right way to go here. pugi::xml_node ctor from a pointer argument is indeed undocumented; it is supposed to be used for obscure use cases when marshalling a pointer is easy and marshalling a pointer-like object is hard, like bindings to some scripting languages, i.e.: xml_node n1 = ...; xml_node n2(n1.internal_object());.